# react, redux why button is not updating its view after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

so i i've been building admin panel for my app, and main window is dashboard with the list of users, so i can delete, or verify them (for now);
delete part is working fine here, but i struggle with update part (verification of user) when click on the button (ACTIVE) react sends request to server to verify user, and after that i want to update my table (this user with id 51 on which i clicked now should have status 'VERIFIED'instead of  'ACTIVE'

[image]

main questions are:

- why status doesn't update immediately after click, (it does updates after i click again on same status, but then server doesn't allow to send verification 2 times to same user)
- and how should i do this correctly so that status updates immediately after click, of course depending on what the response is from server

code:

Dashboard.jsx

```
const Dashboard = () => {
const isAuth = useSelector(state => state.user.isAuth);
const dashBoardUsers = useSelector(state => state.users);
const dispatch = useDispatch()

useEffect(() => {

    dispatch(getUsers);//axios request to get list of users

}, [dashBoardUsers])

function renderUsersTable() {
    dispatch(getUsers)

    return dashBoardUsers
    .sort(function(a, b) { return a.id > b.id ? 1 : -1})
    .map((user, index) => {
            const { created, email, firstName, id, lastName, roles, status, updated, username, verificationTimesAsked } = user //destructuring
            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{id}</td>
                    <td>{username}</td>
                    <td>{email}</td>
                    <td>{firstName}</td>
                    <td>{lastName}</td>
                    {/* <td>{handleStatus(user)}</td> */}
                    <td><UserStatus user={user}/></td>
                    <td>{created}</td>
                    <td>{updated}</td>
                    <td>{roles.map(r => r.name.split("_").pop()) + ','.slice(0, -1)}</td>
                    <td>{verificationTimesAsked}</td>
                    <td><button className="btn btn-danger" disabled={hasAdminRole(roles)} onClick={() => deleteUserElement(id)}>Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
}

return (
    <div style={{ marginLeft: '10px', marginRight: '10px' }}>
        <h1 className="text-center">Users Dashboard</h1>
        <div className="text-center" id="panel">
            <button type="button" className="btn-light btn btn-outline-primary" onClick={() => {
                dispatch(getUsers());
            }}>load users</button>
        </div>
        <div></div>

        <table id="usersTable" className="table table-bordered" style={{ marginTop: '15px' }}>
            <tbody>
                <tr>{renderTableHeader()}</tr>
                {renderUsersTable()}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
);
};

export default Dashboard;
```

userStatus.jsx:

```
const UserStatus = (props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const [currentStatus, setCurrentStatus] = useState("")

useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentStatus(props.user.status);
    
})

return (
    <div>

        <button type='button' className={currentStatus === 'ACTIVE' ? 'greenStatusButton' : 'blueStatusButton'}
            onMouseOver={(e) => mouseOverButtonColor(e, currentStatus)}
            onMouseLeave={(e) => mouseLeaveButtonColor(e, currentStatus)}
            onClick={(e) => handleStatusClick(props.user, e)}>
            <strong>{currentStatus}</strong>
        </button>

    </div>
);

function handleStatusClick(user, e) {
    console.log('status click userId: ');
    console.log(user.id);
    var answer = window.confirm("Verify user with id: " + user.id + "?");
    if (answer) {
        dispatch(verifyUser(user.id))
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#e1edff';
        e.target.style.color = '#607ac4';
        e.target.textContent = 'VERIFIED';

    }
    else {
    }
}
```

reducer.js:

```
const SET_USERS = "SET_USERS";
const DELETE_USER = "DELETE_USER";
const VERIFY_USER = "VERIFY_USER";

const defaultState =
[

]


export default function userListReducer(state = [], action) {

switch (action.type) {
    case SET_USERS:
        return [...action.payload]
    case DELETE_USER:
        
        return [...state.filter(user => user.id != action.payload)]
    case VERIFY_USER:

        return [...state.map(user => {return user.id === action.payload.id ? 
action.payload : user} )]
        
        // return [...state.filter(user => user.id != action.payload)]   
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

Comment: What is the payload content of the action?

Comment: for verification the action.payload is user object {id, username, status...}

Answer (score 0):

Not getting the complete context, but the answer to this problem shall be somewhere inside your action. Are you using `redux-thunk` as a middleware? In that case, your thunk method shall dispatch another action to update the store with API response.

Comment: it's just confusing to me, because after calling dispatch(verifyUser(user.id)) -> calls async dispatch axios post request, after that reducer seems to change array with new user(with updated status) but update of button text and color is not working properly, even though array is updated, button and text renders incorrect, only after i update the page it catches changes